# Error inflating NumberPicker

Tags: android

Пытаюсь использовать разные вариации NumberPicker, включая классический NumberPicker от андроида. Все варианты вызывают ошибку при попытке открыть активность, в которой находится NumberPicker.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ... :
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class android.widget.NumberPicker
```

xml код (для классического NumberPicker)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_editor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.timer.EditorActivity">
...
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/number_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

    </RelativeLayout>
```

java

```
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
...
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
   NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.number_picker);
   np.setMaxValue(9);
   np.setMinValue(0);}
```

Как я сказала выше, любые кастомные пикеры вызывают такую же ошибку.

Есть предположение, что проблема может быть как-то связана с используемой темой.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#061117</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please translate your question into Russian or ask [here](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: От какого класса наследуется активти?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб от AppCompatActivity

Comment: Покажите разметку целиком. Может там проблема. Вы пробовали просто активти с один только пикером внутри запускать? Также попробуйте отключить InstantRun и сделать clean проекта

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  
Попробовала запустить с одним пикером (тогда это вся разметка). Разницы никакой, к сожалению. 
InstantRun и так отключен, clean проводился.

Comment: Ну... Магия у вас какая-то. А если программно его в разметку добавлять?